# Image width in dynamic height container does not affect container width

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with text, and I want to create a square space on the right side, after text.

I can't just set a fixed `padding-right` because I want to make it work for any text size.

This is what I have:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table class="size-maker" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Hello!</td>
            <td class="ratio-1x1">
                <!-- just 1x1 transparent image to maintain 1x1 aspect ratio when resized -->
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAA1BMVEUAAACnej3aAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAApJREFUCB1jYAAAAAIAAc/INeUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />     
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
        background: #0055cc;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .size-maker {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: white;
    }

    .size-maker .ratio-1x1 {
        height: 100%; /* need for FireFox */
    }
    .size-maker .ratio-1x1 img {
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

    .content {
        background: #00DD00;
        position: absolute;
        top: 150%;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<h3>Task</h3>
<p>Black square should be inside of blue, and green square should have the size of both blue+black</p>
<p style="color: gray;"><em>This should work for any font size <b><code>.size-maker { font-size: ...px; }</code></b></em></p>
```

[**Link to sourcebox**](http://sourcebox.io/d984eade9ccd9289310f2691d04a551d/html)

Comment: is it important to keep the markup you have i.e tables and divs in the specific order you have at the moment? & what do you mean by black square should be inside blue?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **EM** for relative padding.

**[Sourcebox](http://sourcebox.io/a98eed701d34d6b4039d6fc72390f81c/html)**

I just added `padding-right:1.15em` to `.size-maker`

```
.size-maker {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 1.15em;
}
```

Where 1em = 100% of element or parent element font-size.

In this scenario 1.15em will be 115% of 20px (font-size).

Comment: Thank you! The `em` does the trick http://sourcebox.io/60e3673bbfc8aaac84165495dfc658bb/html

Comment: I created a jQuery plugin using this https://github.com/moldcraft/adaptive-switch